# Новые способы регистрации

Tags: регистрация

Доброго всем времени суток!

Давайте поговорим о новых способах регистрации на сайте. Честно говоря, меня немного напрягает по несколько раз вводить капчу и ломать глаза, вглядываясь в эти... иероглифы. Плюс ко всему напрягает помнить по несколько пар логин, паролей для разных сайтов. А чем дальше, тем хуже.

Вот я и подумал, а что если...

1. **Регистрация через камеру.** Тут есть несколько способов. Первый - это фотографировать лицо и потом сверять с определенной погрешностью. Второй - жесты. О них мало что слышал, но думаю такая же схема, как и в первом способе,только надежность больше (в первом - можно фотографию поднести).
2. **Регистрация с помощью флешки.** Указанный при регистрации email шифруется и предлагается путь для сохранения. Т.е. email выступает в роли ключа для шифрования (симметричное шифрование). Знаю только, что в некоторых банках используется данная схема (вторая), но только в качестве шифрования пароля.

Как вы думаете, есть ли смысл заморачиваться (изучать, копать, тестить) по данной теме? 
Есть какие-то еще новые способы регистрации? И самое интересное, какие у вас есть идеи для новых способов регистрации?

Подразумевается использовать в банковских и CRM-системах.

Comment: пока нету альтернатив стандартной регистрации

Answer (score 4):

Смысл в том, чтобы заморачиваться, определённо есть. Вопрос удобной регистрации (и последующей авторизации) в данный момент далёк от своего окончательного решения.

Мне лично корень проблемы видится в том, что к этому процессу разные стороны предъявляют противоположные требования. Тот, кто авторизуется, желает максимальной простоты, а тот, кто авторизует, наоборот, хочет максимальной надёжности и сложности. Надёжность призвана обеспечить аутентичность, а сложность - отсутствие автоматических ботов.

В результате все существующие решения представляют собой какую-то разновидность компромисса между этими противоречивыми требованиями. Одни решения делают упор на простоту для пользователя, жертвуя надёжностью (например, сквозная авторизация через Google или Facebook). Другие же предпочитают высокую надёжность в ущерб простоте (асимметричная криптография). Любой из этих вариантов более-менее подходит для своих задач, но для того, чтобы окончательно закрыть вопрос, нужно универсальное решение.

А вот с этим как раз очень большие проблемы. Все существующие решения, претендующие на роль универсальных, по факту являются довольно убогими. Понятно, почему так получается. Теория систем учит нас тому, что любой компромисс между противоположными требованиями заведомо хуже любой из крайних альтернатив (потому что ни рыба, ни мясо). Поэтому поиск универсального решения на пространстве компромисса между двумя идеальными в чём-то крайностями заведомо бесперспективен. Там нет удачного решения.

Искать нужно где-то в стороне. К сожалению, пока ещё никто не придумал, где именно следует искать. Более того, нет никаких гарантий того, что универсальное решение вообще существует. История знает разные примеры. Бывает, что никому так и не удаётся взглянуть на проблему под таким углом, чтобы противоположные требования перестали быть противоположными. Но бывают и успешные прорывы. Короче говоря, ясно одно. Тот, кто сможет вырваться за границы привычных стереотипов и, благодаря этому, придумать элегантное универсальное решение, безусловно, войдёт в историю. Конечно, не всеобщую, а только компьютерную... но и это уже кое-что.

Comment: Дуров когда-то сказал "Компромисс хуже любой из альтернатив." Мне эта фраза очень запомнилась...

Comment: Дуров просто повторил удачную мысль. Она известна людям очень давно. Мне известно два её воплощения, но не исключено, что есть ещё. Среди так называемых Законов Мерфи есть в том числе и Закон Джухэни, который выражает эту идею. Ещё есть Теория решения изобретательских задач (ТРИЗ), в которой это утверждение является одним из основных положений.

Answer (score 2):

Пароль всегда под рукой, а точнее в голове. А вот флешка и уж тем более веб-камера не всегда бывает доступна. К тому же, учитывая то, что сейчас огромное количество народа зарегистрированно в популярных соц. сетях, то не вижу проблем делать регистрацию у себя на сайте, используя эти аккаунты/OpenId "в один клик".

Answer (score 2):

Я так понимаю тут все-же речь идет о авторизации...

1. Фото лица - проблемно. Тут не очень простой алгоритм (очень не простой) и погрешности могут быть очень большими. + найти фото человека в наше время совсем не сложно)) Не подходит.
2. Жесты. Зачем жесты? Давайте рисовать что-то мышкой. Идея та-же самая, но не нужно камеры. Снова-таки, как валидировать рисунок? И чем выдумывание набора символов (пароля) отличается от выдумывания рисунка? Только проблем меньше... Не подходит.
3. Электронно-цифровые подписи существуют уже 100лет. Используются для проведения финансовых операций во многих банках. Сайт(операционист, система) генерирует зашифрованный файл по секретному алгоритму, который клиент носит на флешке и авторизовывается с его помощью на всяких интернет-банках и т.д. Ничего нового.

Самая правильная авторизация: логин/пароль + блокировка аккаунта после нескольких неудачных попыток. Ну или как на некоторых сайтах Гугла - показывать Капчу после неудачных попыток авторизации.

ИМХО

Comment: Порадовало про рисование мышкой =). Случаем нет под рукой алгоритма для шифрования готового?
P.S. Существуют определнные способы шифрования по ГОСТу. Скорее всего компании просто пароль используют для шифрования.